# Trailing data error after deploying laravel project

Tags: php, laravel, timestamp, hosting

after I deployed my laravel project i have been getting Trailing data error when writing to updated_at, it has something to do with Carbon,despite having the same timezone when it was in my machine which used to work there.
so how to remove the trailing data from the timestamp?

Answer (score 0):

[This seems relevant to your problem. Does it help?](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/carbon-trailing-data-error?page=0)